# getting this error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
const renderer = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    completed
      ? setTimeout(() => {
          setTimeCompleted(true);
        }, 100)
      : null;
    return (
      <>
        {completed ? null : (
          <StyledSpan>
            {days} Days: {hours} hours: {minutes} minutes: {seconds} seconds
          </StyledSpan>
        )}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Comment: What's problem exactly and what do you want from this method doing?

Comment: This mostly happens when you use curly braces i.e {} to return an object literal expression.

Comment: I want to use a counter in my site @SachinYadav

Comment: What are you using to manage the state